# The following code is working in eclipse but when i convert into maven project this code giving error

Tags: java, json, maven

This is following is my code, which just read the **JSON** array .this is working in java and display the h1 but when same code if put in maven then it is giving compile time error.

`[ERROR] \WebApp_maven\SimpleCar1\src\main\resources\com\snefotics\servlets\One.java:[39,16] error: constructor JSONArray in class JSONArray cannot be applied to
given types`

this code i wrote in the servlet Get method.

```
    String user1 = "{'Main':[{'h1':[ {'userId':'userId123'} ],'body':[{'data': [{'userId':'one'}]}] }]}";
    JSONObject jsonObj1 = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(user1);
    JSONArray main = (jsonObj1.getJSONArray("Main"));
    JSONArray one=new JSONArray(main.getJSONObject(0).getString("h1"));
    System.out.println("the h1 value is"+one);
```

Comment: Have you written the constructor? If so can you show us the code?

Comment: You can't have java code in an xml file ... or at least you shouldn't.

Comment: I do not think so , can you please try googling for pom.xml and then have a look at what have you posted

Comment: if i remove above line then no errro.

Comment: this is url of my pom.xml file
http://www.viewdocsonline.com/document/adpl5d

Comment: i did not used any constructor i am using lib for net.sf.json.JSONArray;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i check your pom.xml and code this problem will comes only the mismatch the version json-lib-0.9  and json-lib-2.4 or other version of library so you remove all library and try the following way and one more things you have to remove from json-lib from apche-tomacat lib also and then you try this following code and used the json-lib 2.4 version.

```
    String user1 = "{'Main':[{'h1':[ {'userId':'userId123'} ],'body':[{'data': [{'userId':'one'}]}] }]}";

    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(user1);
    JSONArray snefoCareEnvelopeMain = (jsonObj.getJSONArray("Main"));                   
    //main object
    JSONObject  Main =  snefoCareEnvelopeMain.getJSONObject(0);

    // this for reading h1 data

    JSONArray  headerarray = (Main.getJSONArray("h1"));
    JSONObject h1=headerarray.getJSONObject(0);
    System.out.println("the first value is :"+h1.getString("userId"));


    //for body
    JSONArray bodyarray=(Main.getJSONArray("body"));
    JSONObject bodyobject=bodyarray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray dataArary=bodyobject.getJSONArray("data");
    JSONObject data=dataArary.getJSONObject(0);
    System.out.println("the body is"+data);
```

i hope this will resolve your problem